# Importing Matlab Engine in Python: OSError version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: python, matlab

when I followed the instructions on the MathWorks page (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) and want to run the command
`import matlab.engine` 
The follwoing Error occur:

```
enter code here

runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram  /main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')
Reloaded modules: shapely.geometry, shapely.algorithms.cga, fiona.compat, shapely.geometry.polygon, pyproj._proj, shapely.geometry.linestring, _proj, fiona._err, shapely.geometry.base, shapely.ftools, shapely.linref, shapely.ops, shapely.predicates, shapely.wkt, _internal, centerline.io, shapely.geometry.geo, shapely.topology, fiona.ogrext, mlarray, _internal.mlarray_utils, shapely.coords, shapely.affinity, shapely.geometry.collection, matlab, shapely.geometry.proxy, centerline.utils, shapely.ctypes_declarations, mlexceptions, fiona.rfc3339, fiona._geometry, shapely, _internal.mlarray_sequence, fiona._drivers, fiona.drvsupport, fiona, shapely.geometry.multipoint, pyproj, shapefile, shapely.speedups, centerline.main, shapely.algorithms, shapely.speedups._speedups, shapely.geometry.multipolygon, pyproj.datadir, shapely.geometry.point, fiona.errors, shapely.impl, shapely.geometry.multilinestring, fiona.collection, shapely.geos, shapely.errors, centerline
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-2-820f256278b1>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py', wdir='/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram')

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 88, in execfile
exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/media/mattes/data1/dataDMattes/Code/Python/PythonProgram/main.py", line 42, in <module>
import matlab.engine

File "/home/mattes/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matlab/engine/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
'MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: %s' % e)

OSError: Please reinstall MATLAB Engine for Python or contact MathWorks Technical Support for assistance: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/extern/engines/python/dist/matlab/engine/glnxa64/../../../../../../../bin/glnxa64/libmwengine_api.so)
```

I also tried to reinstall the Matlab Engine and used instead of the suggested command from Mathworks (`python setup.py install`) the following one:

```
python setup.py build --build-base=$(mktemp -d) install
```

I use Python 3.5.2 and have MATLAB R2018a in Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Does someone has an idea?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: »»GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found«« : You can unpack `libstdc++.so.6 ->  libstdc++.so.6.0.22` in e.g. your $HOME, and include it when you run the command : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/[name]/libstdc++6_6.3.0_amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && [command]` ... Link to "libstdc++6_6.3.0_amd64.tar.gz" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13vAV3uHH3nUbJOw2A7kc_2EhDUeOLxMj?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I will test it on monday when I´m back at work. I´m new to Python, what is the `[command]` you mentioned for the `LD_LIBRARY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

You can unpack `libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.22` in e.g. your $HOME, and include it when you run the command : Example →

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/[name]/libstdc++6_6.3.0_amd64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && import matlab.engine
```

> what is ... [command]

[command] means "any command" to be used with the `libstdc++.so.6` in $HOME.

About the folder libstdc++6_6.3.0_amd64/ : You can rename to e.g. `lib64` to have a shorter file name : /home/[name]/lib64/ →

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/[name]/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && import matlab.engine
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try it as soon as possible!